# ALT+S key press using Robot Class not working when used along with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

I am automating a scenario using Selenium Webdriver. When I click on the button using the selenium java script in IE, it downloads an excel file(shown in image-popup).
However I need to click on the "Save" option in that bar, so that it gets downloaded at the default location.
Since selenium does not provide the support for clicking the file download browser popup, so i have tried using robot class fuctionality.

The code which i have used is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnGenerateExtract']/span/span")).click();
    //some wait of 4 seconds
    clickOnSave();
```

Code for clickOnSave():

```
{
            Robot robot=new Robot();
            robot.setAutoDelay(250);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
}
```

However, this is not working as it is not able to click on the "save" option.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved with a minor change in the script.
Instead of

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnGenerateExtract']/span/span")).click();

use JavascriptExecutor as,

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnGenerateExtract']/span/span")));

Rest of the keyboard or mouse events could be performed using Robot class.

Answer (score -1):

You can rather stop the browser asking for prompt to "Save or Open" or specify the default save location manually.

Link:

https://superuser.com/questions/273372/how-to-get-ie8-to-auto-save-downloaded-files-to-a-specific-directory

Comment: Even though this might turn out to be a temporary fix, but i cannot expect all the utility users to make such changes in "regedit". I would like to have some better way to handle this scenario. Pls suggest.